# Cannot install vagrant-chef library in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, vagrant, chef-infra

I have recently learned about vagrant so i thought why dont i give it a try. I wanted to setup vagrant for rails development. I successfully installed virtualbox, vagrant and also i was successful to install **vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest** then when i tried **vagrant plugin install vagrant-librarian-chef
** it gives me error.
Following is the error

```
bishisht@bishisht:~$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-librarian-chef
Installing the 'vagrant-librarian-chef' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:562:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/bishisht/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/bishisht/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/ffi-1.9.5/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:540:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:515:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:515:in `build_extensions'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:180:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:297:in `block in install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `each_with_index'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `install'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:65:in `block in call'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/gem_helper.rb:42:in `block in with_environment'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:40:in `use_ui'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/gem_helper.rb:41:in `with_environment'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:52:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/action/bundler_check.rb:20:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/base.rb:17:in `action'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:27:in `execute'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/root.rb:56:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/cli.rb:38:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:484:in `cli'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:127:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need the "mkmf" Ruby gem and probably other build tools in order to proceed.